# Android Map Save Markers on destroying the app

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am creating an Android App where I want to create marker at my current location and also display previous such markers. I am able to create marker at my current location and also display such markers as long as I am pausing the app and resuming it again. But once I destroy the app and start it again I loose all such markers. Here is what I have tried:

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
public Location mLastLocation;
ArrayList<LatLng> listOfPoints = new ArrayList<>();
public boolean isMapReady = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

}
}


public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
   mMap = googleMap;
   isMapReady = true;
}

 public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
  return false;
 }

 public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
  if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,      android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    return;
}
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    return;
}
mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
        mGoogleApiClient);

MarkerOptions mp = new MarkerOptions();
mp.position(new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude()));

mp.title("my position");

mMap.addMarker(mp);

mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
        new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude()), 16));
LatLng newLatLng = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());
listOfPoints.add(newLatLng);


 }

 public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

 }

public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

protected void onStart() {
super.onStart();
mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

protected void onStop() {
super.onStop();
mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();

}

protected void onPause() {
super.onPause();
try {
    // Modes: MODE_PRIVATE, MODE_WORLD_READABLE, MODE_WORLD_WRITABLE
    FileOutputStream output = openFileOutput("latlngpoints.txt",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(output);
    dout.writeInt(listOfPoints.size()); // Save line count
    for (LatLng point : listOfPoints) {
        dout.writeUTF(point.latitude + "," + point.longitude);
        Log.v("write", point.latitude + "," + point.longitude);
    }
    dout.flush(); // Flush stream ...
    dout.close(); // ... and close.
} catch (IOException exc) {
    exc.printStackTrace();
}
}

 protected void onResume(){
super.onResume();
if (isMapReady==true){
    try {
        FileInputStream input = openFileInput("latlngpoints.txt");
        DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(input);
        int sz = din.readInt(); // Read line count
        for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
            String str = din.readUTF();
            Log.v("read", str);
            String[] stringArray = str.split(",");
            double latitude = Double.parseDouble(stringArray[0]);
            double longitude = Double.parseDouble(stringArray[1]);
            listOfPoints.add(new LatLng(latitude, longitude));
        }
        din.close();
        loadMarkers(listOfPoints);
    } catch (IOException exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
 protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

outState.putParcelableArrayList("places",  listOfPoints);
}
 private void restore(Bundle outState){
if (outState != null) {
    listOfPoints =(ArrayList<LatLng>)outState.getSerializable("places");
}
}
 protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
super.onRestoreInstanceState(outState);
restore(outState);
isMapReady = true;
}
private void loadMarkers(List<LatLng> listOfPoints) {
int i=listOfPoints.size();
while(i>0){
    i--;
    double Lat=listOfPoints.get(i).latitude;
    double Lon=listOfPoints.get(i).longitude;
    MarkerOptions mp = new MarkerOptions();

    mp.position(new LatLng(Lat, Lon));

    mp.title("my previous position");

    mMap.addMarker(mp);

    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
            new LatLng(Lat, Lon), 16));
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might not be loosing the latlngs but, u need to be more smart on using onResume().
When on fresh load, Map might not be ready for use in OnResume() method and hence, it is not entering in if block.

Comment: I updated my onRestoreInstance by updating isMapReady boolean flag as true. But still no luck.

Comment: Can you take out whole thing written in onResume to a method. And call it from onResume as well as from onMapReady.